# Correct way to append html to Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<section class="section1">
    //Section one content
</section>
<section class="section2">
    <h4>Some Title</h4>

    <input type="hidden" class="keys" value="1"/>
    <div id="block-close-1"></div>
    <div class="block" id="block-1">
          //Block content
    </div>

</section>

<section class="section3">
    //Section3 content    
</section>
```

What I want to do is take some html and insert it after "block-1"

The HTML I wish to add looks like this:

```
    <input type="hidden" class="keys" value="2"/>
    <div id="block-close-2"></div>
    <div class="block" id="block-2">
          //Block content
    </div>
```

I have tried this:

```
var html = '//code as above';
$( "html" ).insertAfter( "#block-1");
```

The error I get is this:

> Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed
>    to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The new child element contains
>    the parent.

I have also tried this:
    document.getElementById('#block-4').appendChild(html);

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

What is the correct way to add new HTML to the existing HTML?

Comment: In your case `html` is a variable, so you have to use `$(html).insertAfter( "#block-1");` (without quotes (as @Elentriel answered)) or use code like this `$("<div>some html...</div>").insertAfter( "#block-1");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `$(html)` not  `$("html")`

The first tries to add the contents of the variable html, the second tries to find the tag html on the DOM and add it~

Comment: But of course my pleasure :)
Add this as accepted answer if it helped you

Answer (score 5):

The native JavaScript approach would be this:

`document.getElementById("block-1").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend",html);`

jQuery approach:

`$("#block-1").after(html);`

Comment: Plus one for native js:)

Answer (score 5):

From jQuery documentation for [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) ...

> The .after() and .insertAfter() methods perform the same task. The
>   major difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of
>   the content and target. With .after(), the selector expression
>   preceding the method is the container after which the content is
>   inserted. With .insertAfter(), on the other hand, the content precedes
>   the method, either as a selector expression or as markup created on
>   the fly, and it is inserted after the target container.

That is, if you want to place your new html after `block-1` you select block-1 and call insertAfter() on it, passing the new html as the parameter -

```
$('#block-1').insertAfter( $(html) );
```

Or you could keep the order you have if it's more intuitive to you, but use `.after()`

```
$(html).after($('#block-1'));
```